# Circles with percentage values in center Showing results of a set of number of checkboxes checked under different categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a java script showing results in the form of circles with percentage values at the center which are returned as a result of number of checkboxes checked under in different categories. The radius of the circle need to be calculated based on percentage vaues. say, 40% small, 80% bigger than that.

For Eg,

Environment:

1. Keep Your Environment clean,
2. Avoid pollution.

   Nature:
3. Preserve Nature.
4. Grow trees.

   If in the Environment section, 1 checkbox is checked and if in Nature, 2 checkboxes are checked then Nature need to have High percent value showing the percent value at the center of the circle and Environment with low percent value showing smaller circle with percent value at center. I need to have 5 circle like that. Could someone help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Google Pie Charts for this:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: I don't think he meant pie charts.. More like different sized bullet points based on the importance of the subject...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

JavaScript:

```
   $(function(){

    var maxWidth = 500, // This is the max width of your circle

    percent = Number($('#result').text()); // This is the percentage value

    percent = percent / 100;

    $("#circle").css({

        "width" : maxWidth * percent,

        "height" : maxWidth * percent,


    });
});
```

CSS:

```
  #circle {

    border: 1px solid red;

    border-radius: 50%;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    background:blue;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like? http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/xP25c/

```
function createCircles(value1, value2, value3, value4) {
    $('.one').css({
        width: value1 * 2,
        height: value1 * 2,
        lineHeight: value1  / 10
    }).text(value1 + '%');
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
createCircles(20,50,5,15);
```

where those numbers are the values.

Or I created a jQuery plugin for something similar a while back:

http://zhereicome.com/experiments/statics/statisquares/